# To call this a "rook-pawn endgame" ... just a typo?

Tags: endgame, bishop-endgame

In this chess.com tutorial, the caption describes this as a rook-pawn endgame.  It seems likely to me this is a typo.  But being a noob, I wanted to be sure it wasn't a reference to some well known style of endgame which, although known as "rook-pawn", is more widely applicable?

[image: chess.com tutorial]

Comment: It's not "rook and pawn", but rather "rook-pawn", meaning a pawn on the edge of the board.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson  Thank you. It really didn't occur to me that "rook" is an adjective meaning "on the rook's file".

Comment: This goes with the old "descriptive notation" where e.g. the Spanish / Ruy Lopez might start 1 P-K4 P-K4 2 N-KB3 N-QB3 3 B-N5 P-QR3 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caption shows that it is not called a "rook=pawn" endgame but a "wrong colored bishop rook-pawn endgame".

This is indeed a well known endgame. The rook's pawn's queening square is h1 which is white, while black's bishop controls the black squares. That means the bishop cannot be used to force the white king away from h1 and so white will draw the game.

For example:

```
[fen "8/8/8/2b5/6kp/8/7K/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Kh1 h3 2. Kh2 Kh4 3. Kh1 Kg3= (3... Kg4 4. Kh2 Kh4 5. Kh1 Kg4 6. Kh2 Kh4= (6... Kf3 7. Kxh3=))
```

White will either be stalemated, take the pawn or get a 3-fold repetition.

Now see what would happen if the bishop was the "right-colored bishop":

```
[fen "8/8/8/1b6/6kp/8/7K/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Kh1 h3 2. Kh2 Bc6 {Not allowing the white king into the corner} 3. Kg1 Kg3 4. Kf1 h2 5. Ke2 h1=Q
```

Comment: Thank you. It really didn't occur to me that "rook" is an adjective meaning "on the rook's file".

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Brian Towers's answer, pawns are usually referred to by the piece starting at their column. This is a legacy of the [descriptive notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_notation) system that used to be popular before algebraic notation became standard.

This convention of referring to pawns as "rook pawn", "knight pawn", "bishop pawn" and "central pawn" is still useful in endgames due to the symmetry of the board. In other words, endgames featuring an "a" pawn will show the same themes as those with an "h" pawn. In openings and middlegames it's not as useful since king safety is a key factor therefore events happening on the kingside are usually different from those on the queenside. For instance, the King's Gambit and Queen's Gambit lead to totally different types of positions, but a pawn endgame is usually the same as its mirror image